# Can we create a Silverlight Socket Server ONLY using SILVERLIGHT and XML's (NO WCF WPF CONSOL APPS)?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, sockets

Can we create a  Silverlight Socket Server ONLY using SILVERLIGHT and XML's (NO WCF WPF CONSOL APPS)?

---

**If yes.**
 What do I need

- MSDN if there is any help on this.
- Open Source Libs/wrappers for encoding/decoding.
- Tutorials and blog articles on How to do it.

---

**If no** I need where did you get the info from (link to MSDN or other official SL resource)

---

*Please say in your answer "YES" or "NO" if you think "YES" or "NO"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248(VS.95).aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx