# Silverlight 5 to act as a localhost web server

Tags: .net, silverlight

With Silverlight 5 in-browser application, will I be able to open a listening post on a client machine so my silverlight object acts as a local web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Silverlight can connect to a socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (normally limited to ports: 4502-453) and when the the app is running out of browser you are free to pick any port.

It is not possible to open a listening socket.

See also: [Can we create a Silverlight Socket Server ONLY using SILVERLIGHT and XML's (NO WCF WPF CONSOL APPS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670661/can-we-create-a-silverlight-socket-server-only-using-silverlight-and-xmls-no-w)